# 403 Forbidden error via ZUUL only

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I get the following error:

```
Aug 08, 2016 12:40:45 PM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
SEVERE: 
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:503)
at com.primedex2.mservice.ui.trader.TradersRepo.modifyTrader1Step(TradersRepo.java:451)
```

whenever i call a put, delete or post via the restfull API:

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> exchange(String url, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> responseType, Map<String, ?> uriVariables) throws RestClientException {
Type type = responseType.getType();
RequestCallback requestCallback = this.httpEntityCallback(requestEntity, type);
ResponseExtractor responseExtractor = this.responseEntityExtractor(type);
return (ResponseEntity)this.execute(url, method, requestCallback, responseExtractor, uriVariables);
```

it works perfectly when I set the direct link (not via zuul.)
Does anyone has an idea or had the same struggle?

Comment: zuul is used for authentication (also other stuff), check your configuration. see docs http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html

Comment: I'm aware of that,  GET calls work. there is no authentication implemented yet and we use ZUUL for rooting together with eureka. why would i get a 403?

Comment: maybe your problem is related to cors, check if you get headers duplicated, check you cors filter.

Comment: A small sample application on GitHub that reproduces the issue would help a lot..

Comment: @Timur, I wonder if you were ever able to solve this issue...?

Comment: Any solution for this?